# Why do generators need a complete circuit to move electrons but capacitors do not?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, charge, capacitance

A charged capacitor will shock you if you come too close to it or touch it, and you are connected to the ground. A generator will only generate electricity if it has a complete circuit, it cannot just be connected to something which is connected to the ground. Why is this?

Comment: The answer is much simpler: what's teh voltage of both elements? OF course a 9V generator is much more inoffensive than a 4000V capacitor.

Comment: You will only get a shock if one plate of the capacitor is connected to the ground and the same is true of a terminal of the generator.

Comment: If you touch the two ends of a charged  capacitor you will complete the circuit and be shocked--no grounding required anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you touch the hot wire coming from a generator while standing on the ground, you will get shocked. There's no need to complete the circuit back to the generator, the current can absolutely flow even though it's "just connected to something which is connected to the ground".

Your premise is flawed.

Comment: If it matters that you are "standing on the ground," that's because the ground _is_ a conductor that completes the circuit.  Maybe not a very good conductor, but good enough.

Comment: Yes, my point is that the circuit isn't completed *back to the generator*. It's of course still a complete circuit, otherwise current wouldn't flow at all.

Comment: Then why do single phase AC power lines need a return wire?

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is given relatively. Have a generator that produces 1V, and a Cap at the same voltage, both can have a potential against Ground of 1MV. Touch one, and you may get ahocked, **depending on your potential against Ground**